# Problem with Mapbox navigation in flutter

Tags: flutter, mapbox

I'm trying to make a turn by turn navigation app with flutter but I have a problem. I am using the Mapbox navigation package and I want the navigation screen to remain in the screen where I called it, not to open another screen. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to navigate based on markers, you can do that using the `ontap` method inside the marker function.

```
onTap: (){
     Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Page()),);
         }
```

you can do the navigation replacing the `Page` to which ever widget you want.